# How to make a service run even after exiting docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, service, containers

all

Currently, I have written a service in the docker container.
Currently, when I exit from my container my service is not running which is expected but when I see
"sudo docker exec -it  ps -ef" it shows that MySQL which is installed in my container is up and running if I want the same kind of behavior to my service then what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run your container detached* with

`docker run -d <image_name>`

Thanks

Comment: Not meaning to nitpick but `-d` actually means 'detached'; as in the console detaches from STDOUT of the service container after startup. https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#usage